# Компиляция под Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ассемблер, gcc

Пытаюсь скомпилить элементарный код:

```
.globl main

.text

main:
    call rand
    ret
```

пишу: **gcc -m32 -g prog.S -o prog**, получаю кучу ошибок, что нет **.o**-файлов. Нахожу эти файлы (Scrt1.o, crti.o, libgcc_s.so.1), копирую в папку с исходником. Запускаю ещё раз, получаю:

```
skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
cannot find -lgcc
skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Что с этим делать? Почему не работает? Копирование libgcc.a не помогает, естественно. И что такое **-lgcc** вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вы пытаетесь скомпилировать 32-ух битное приложение в 64-ёх битном окружении. Компоновщик жалуется на несовместимость библиотек. Чтобы установить нужные файлы поставьте пакет [gcc-multilib](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-multilib&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all). Либо собирайте под 64 бита, убрав для этого флаг `-m32`.

---

> Копирование libgcc.a не помогает, естественно. И что такое -lgcc вообще?

Естественно. Дело в том, что компоновщик ищет библиотеки по определённому правилу:

- Аргумент у каждого ключа `-lбиблиотека` воспринимаются как название библиотеки.
- Из этого названия составляется имя файла: либо `libбиблиотека.so`, либо `libбиблиотека.a`. Что берётся раньше, зависит от наличия флагов `-shared` или `-static` соответственно. По умолчанию используются разделяемые библиотеки. Виды библиотек можно комбинировать.
- Затем эти файлы ищутся в каталогах, перечисленных с помощью ключей `-L/путь/к/папке`. По порядку компоновщик пытается открыть либо .so файл, либо .a файл (про порядок выше). Если находится совместимая библиотека, — она используется. По умолчанию среди этого списка нету текущего каталога или каталога, где лежат исходники. Но можно добавить их вручную. Например, `-L.`
- Полный список использующихся ключей можно получить, добавив флаг `-v` к вызову компилятора.

Comment: Да, так и есть, я компилирую 32 в 64. Сейчас поставлю gcc-multilib, спасибо. А как сделать, чтобы не пришлось копировать Scrt1.o, crti.o, libgcc_s.so.1 в папку с исходником?

Comment: @JinX, есть подозрение, что это копирование не требуется

Comment: После установки gcc-multilib уже не требуется! СПАСИБО, всё заработало ;)

Comment: У меня почему-то после компиляции получается другой результат, чем хочется. В частности, вызов той же функции **rand** осуществляется напрямую, а не через трамплин. Мне же нужно, чтобы функция вызывалась через трамплин... Как это сделать?

Comment: К сожалению, я не очень разбираюсь в ассемблерных жаргонах. Вероятно, вам стоит [задать новый вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Ну и да, в принципе, тело вашей функции эквивалентно простому `jmp rand`

Comment: Почему jmp? call же...

Comment: call кладёт текщий адрес (значение регистра eip) в регистр стека (esp) и переходит по указанной метке. Затем вызываемая функция выполняет ret, которая вынимает из стека адрес возврата (уменьшает значение регистра esp) и переходит по нему. Затем тут же вызывающая функция также выполняет ret. Можно оптимизировать использование стека и двойное выполение ret (что по сути является декрементом esp), если не делать call / ret, а просто сразу перейти в вызываемую функцию. А она уж в конце своей работы вернёт управление, откуда была вызвана "наша" текущая вызываемая функция (в данном случае main).

Comment: Всё это для x86. Вообще говоря, тема довольно обширна и не очень вписывается в формат шестисотсимвольных комментариев. Вам стоит ознакомиться с дополнительными источниками. Годную ссылку, к сожалению, привести не могу.

Comment: Это я всё знаю, понял теперь что Вы имели в виду. Да, по сути функция эквивалентна простому **jmp** :))... Только несколько поправок: **esp** не уменьшается после **ret**, а увеличивается (на 4 в 32 битах), т.к. стек растёт вниз. А при вызове (**call**) **eip** кладётся не в **esp**, а сначала **esp** уменьшается на 4, а затем по адресу **[esp]** кладётся **eip**.

Comment: да, спасибо за ценные уточнения — кроме как универского курса не имел дела с ассемблером)))

Answer (score 0):

Вы непредоставили весь лог ошибок. Но я предпологаю , что в Вашем исходном коде  компилятор помечает метку `main` как данные . Поэтому линковшик не находит функцию `main` и выдает ошибки. Первая программа на asm под линукс

```
.data
  hello_str:
  .string "Hello, world!\n"
  .set hello_str_length, . - hello_str - 1 
.text
.globl  main 
.type   main, @function
main:
   movl   $4, %eax
   movl   $1, %ebx
   movl   $hello_str, %ecx
   movl   $hello_str_length, %edx 
   int    $0x80
   movl   $1, %eax
   movl   $4, %ebx
   int    $0x80
.size   main, .-main
```

Comment: Это весь лог ошибок. Ваш вариант не помогает. Всё то же самое.

Comment: Кстати, а чем отличается **.set** от простого присвоения **a=1234** ?